# How to mock browser globals in playwright?

Tags: mocking, playwright

I'm looking for a way to mock a global variable in playwright tests.

I tried running

```js
page.evaluate(() => {
  window.myVar = jest.fn();
});
```

however, I get `page.evaluate: ReferenceError: jest is not defined` - which makes sense since the evaluation is running in the browser and jest is in the runner...

Is there a way to mock things in the browser?

(for context, why I want to do this - I am creating a google apps script app which always has the `google` api available at runtime, so I need to mock that in my tests...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exposeFunction` to run code on your side:

```
await page.exposeFunction('myMock', () => console.log('This function runs on the node side'));
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.myVar = myMock();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, exposing a function worked for my own function, however, I cannot get `jest.fn()` exposed, it always says "Unexpected value" :/

Comment: yeah. You might need to build some wrapper that uses that  `jest.fn()` .

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not quite sure how I would do that and also how I would then assert on the mocks... Is that even possible? Could you please add that to your answer? I'd like to accept it :)